# Prestashop 1.7.5 Custom PHP code, where to place

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, prestashop

I have a piece of custom PHP code that I need to place somewhere in the file structure that would be accessible on all pages (cart, cats, cms, etc...). I have done digging around and see all fingers pointed at the controllers directory. I'm not really sure where/how to make the addition. I've tried to create a module, but getting stuck - abandoning this idea due to time crunch. Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Also I should note that I would need to access the output of the custom PHP code via AJAX from the frontend. I have all this hooked up and working on just a simple setup (XAMPP) php.php & js.js just need to know how to integrate it within Prestashop's structure.

Ideally this code would run early on in the lifecycles, and if I don't have to override any core file/s, even better.

Thanks so much for any help.

Using PS version 1.7.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [PrestaShop module creator](https://validator.prestashop.com/generator)

You have to add displayHeader Hook on wizard to create this hook on your module and place you php code in it.

To send variable to js files:

```
Media::addJsDef(['jsVar' => 'value']);
```

Comment: Thanks Mahdi. So with the addJsDef method I can pass anything in the second parameter and console log it from a js file?

Comment: yes. also you can pass array of variables to js using addJsDef.

Comment: I just created and installed a test module but seems to not be working correctly. Inside the 'hookDisplayHeader' i placed 'Media::addJsDef('simVar' => 'Test.');' and inside the module's js/front.js i tried to console log 'simVar' but nothing happened. Here the file structure https://ibb.co/7kjygkq Thank you again.

Comment: You have to load your js file. use $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'views/js/front.js');

Comment: I still cannot get the addJsDef method to send some info over to JS files. And yes I have the addJS methods that were created automatically via the module creator

Comment: can you post function details at the end of your first post?

Comment: also you have to turn debug mod on to display your errors. search : How to turn on error reporting in PrestaShop

Comment: Go to admin panel -> Configure -> Performance -> Debug Mode. And also turn off all cache and set template compilation to "Recompile templates if the files have been updated" or to force recompilation

Comment: I got this working by changing the `Media::addJsDef('jsVar' => 'value');` to `Media::addJsDef('jsVar', 'value');` I don't have an array of js files so I just need to pass one file name.